# Swift 3/Realm - Como filtrar um Object dentro de outro filtro

Tags: swift, realmdb

Minha intenção é filtrar uma única linha dentro dos resultados do filtro anterior, mas retornando o mesmo tipo, para que eu possa realizar um terceiro filtro.
Eis a minha tentativa:

```
    func salvarDadosAluno(_codPessoa: String, _codCurso: String){

    let realm = try! Realm()

    let aluno = realm.objects(Alunos.self).filter("codPessoa == %@", _codPessoa).first

    //Cannot convert value of type 'Alunos' to expected 'Object.type'
    let curso = realm.objects(aluno).filter("codCurso == %@", _codCurso).first

    print(cursos)

    }
```

Eis o meu DB:

```
class Alunos : Object{

   dynamic var codPessoa: String = ""
   dynamic var raPessoa: String = ""
   dynamic var nomePessoa: String = ""
   let cursos = List<Cursos>()
}

class Cursos : Object{

   dynamic var codCurso: String = ""
   dynamic var desCurso: String = ""
   let disciplinas = List<Disciplinas>()

}
```

E com o resultado dessas buscas, eu desejo inserir mais disciplinas pra essa aluno, nesse curso filtrado, como isso:

```
try! realm.write {

            curso?.disciplinas.append(curso)

}
```

Como proceder?
Agradeço qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a dinâmica deve ser outra. 
Primeiro precisamos buscar o objeto **Cursos** com o código **_codCurso** especificado. Para isso:

```
let predicateCursos = NSPredicate(format: "codCurso == %@", _codCursos)
let curso = realm.objects(Cursos.self).filter(predicateCursos).first // retorna Cursos?
```

Com esse resultado, podemos seguir em frente com a busca do objeto **Alunos**:

```
if  let curso = realm.objects(Cursos.self).filter(predicateCursos).first {
    let predicateAlunos = NSPredicate(format: "codPessoa == %@ AND NOT %@ IN cursos", _codPessoa, curso)
    let aluno = realm.objects(Alunos.self).filter(predicateAlunos).first
    // Retorna Alunos?. Acima o aluno com o código _codPessoa que não possui o curso com o código _codCursos
}
```

Dessa forma você tem na variável **aluno** o resultado da sua busca: alunos que ainda não fazem o curso **_codCurso**.

> E com o resultado dessas buscas, eu desejo inserir mais disciplinas
>   pra essa aluno, nesse curso filtrado

```
try! realm.write {
     curso?.disciplinas.append(curso)
}
```

No caso acima há uma incoerência no seu código: a variável *disciplinas* é uma lista do objeto **Disciplinas** e você está tentando inserir um **Cursos** nela. De qualquer forma, Crie/busque o objeto **Disciplinas** primeiro antes de inseri-lo na propriedade **disciplinas**.